# Strange error with Rails HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am having strange error with following case of HABTM relationship

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :outlets
end

class Outlet < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end
```

produced very strange error when I try to add outlets in deal

```
@deal.outlets << @outlet
@deal.outlet_ids = [1]
```

I am getting following

```
Outlet Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "outlets".* FROM "outlets"   ORDER BY "outlets"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "" does not exist
LINE 5:               AND cons.conrelid = '""'::regclass
                                          ^
:             SELECT attr.attname
            FROM pg_attribute attr
            INNER JOIN pg_constraint cons ON attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
            WHERE cons.contype = 'p'
              AND cons.conrelid = '""'::regclass

   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "" does not exist
LINE 5:               AND cons.conrelid = '""'::regclass
                                          ^
:             SELECT attr.attname
            FROM pg_attribute attr
            INNER JOIN pg_constraint cons ON attr.attrelid = cons.conrelid AND attr.attnum = cons.conkey[1]
            WHERE cons.contype = 'p'
              AND cons.conrelid = '""'::regclass
```

Comment: Make sure @outlet is valid as per the association.

Comment: \@outlet is valid instance of Outlet model @sansarp :)

Comment: so you are getting error in your second query, right?

Comment: yes, strange is I am able to get correct records if I enter data in relational table manually @sansarp

Comment: you could do like this: @deal.update_all(outlet_ids: 1) Hope it works now.

Comment: unfortunately no :( @sansarp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70901/discussion-between-mighty-lucene-and-sansarp).